# jQuery AJAX function can't see my variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code, which i've simplified, where `$currEl` gets logged and displays correctly, but in the $.ajax call it logs as `null`.

Am I missing something?

```
for(var i=0, j = atgSlots.length; i < j; i++) {
 var currSlot = atgSlots[i].split('|'),
   $currEl = currSlot[0].length ? $('[data-atg-url=' + currSlot[0] + ']') : null,
   wcmLocation = currSlot[2] || null;

 if ($currEl !== null && wcmLocation !== null) {
  console.log($currEl);
  $.ajax({
   url: wcmLocation,
   success: function(html) { console.log($currEl); updateSlots.setContent($currEl, html); },
   error: updateSlots.checkDefault
  }); // $.ajax
 }
} // for : atgSlots
```

Comment: Don't put variable declarations inside loops. They should be the first statements in the code, ergo, at the top of the code.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I disagree. I always declare my vars just before they are used, I know there's no real scope beyond function scope in js, but it helps reading the code, there is no downside to doing it.

Comment: @Juan I think that you misunderstood me. I am talking about variable declaration here, not assignment. You can assign values to your variables wherever you want to, that is fine. However, the declaration of a variable (as in `var x;`) should appear at the beginning of the code. Declaring all used variables in this manner **improves** readability.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I didn't misunderstand it, I don't see a need to declare a variable at the top of a function if it's only going to be used within a for loop. I declare them close to where they are used. I think all the variables in one place creates a disconnect, and makes you think that all those variables are important for the whole picture, whereas many of them are only useful within a smaller context in a function.

Comment: @Juan: I totally get what you're saying, but I'm with Šime on this: *"...the further your code gets from expressing what's really happening, the easier it is for someone reading the code later (perhaps you!) to get the wrong end of the stick and introduce a problem."* (http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

Comment: @Juan Good point. In the case you mention, declaring those variables right before the loop sounds reasonable. (But, **not inside the loop** like the OP has done it)

Comment: @Crowder I took a peak at the jQuery source code, and from over 300 var statements, a solid percentage of them are located "somewhere in the middle" of a function. (Oftentimes inside if statements, or in loop headers.) I guess, if you are a professional and you understand your code very well, then you can afford to do it. On the other hand, beginners and sloppy programmers may want to stick to best practices... So it depends...

Comment: I've disagreed about this in the past, so I don't think I'm going to win the argument. We summoned the developers at my previous job and voted that it makes more sense to mimic languages with block level scope and declare it in a block if only used there. I love to declare the var i inside the for loop declaration. If you put it at method beginning, it could be far from where it's used. Just before the loop, it's a wasted line. Same thing for a variable only used within an if statement. @TJ, as you can see I don't agree with that post!

Comment: Last thing, the real problem with declaring them within a block is that an unexperienced developer may be led to think that the variable is no longer defined after the block. But I'm not going to code for beginners if it makes my code harder to read. If it didn't make my code harder to read, I would go ahead and declare them at the top for the sake of beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your ajax success function has a *live reference to* the `$currEl` variable, not a *copy* of it as of when the function was created. Consequently, all of those success handlers are referencing the same variable and therefore the same value — the last value assigned to `$currEl` in the loop. Here's a much, much simplified example of the same effect:

```
var a;
a = "before";
setTimeout(function() {
    alert(a);
}, 10);
a = "after";
```

That alerts "after", not "before", because the function that gets called after 10ms uses the current value of `a`. [See it in action](http://jsbin.com/uwomi3).

You can address this by giving each function its own variable to refer to, using an intermediary function. Here's a minimalist change:

```
for(var i=0, j = atgSlots.length; i < j; i++) {
 var currSlot = atgSlots[i].split('|'),
   $currEl = currSlot[0].length ? $('[data-atg-url=' + currSlot[0] + ']') : null,
   wcmLocation = currSlot[2] || null;

 if ($currEl !== null && wcmLocation !== null) {
  console.log($currEl);
  $.ajax({
   url: wcmLocation,
   // ==== Change starts here
   success: (function($thisEl) {
     return function(html) { console.log($thisEl); updateSlots.setContent($thisEl, html); };
   })($currEl),
   // ==== Change ends here
   error: updateSlots.checkDefault
  }); // $.ajax
 }
} // for : atgSlots
```

What that does is create and call a factory function on each loop, passing into the function the current value of `$currEl`. That function then returns the function that should be used as the success handler. The success handler uses other information from the outer context (`html`, which I'm assuming should be common to all of them), but uses `$thisEl` (the function argument) instead of `$currEl`.

It's actually *slightly* inefficient to do it that way, because we create multiple identical copies of our new factory function. A less minimalist — and perhaps clearer — version would look like this:

```
for(var i=0, j = atgSlots.length; i < j; i++) {
 var currSlot = atgSlots[i].split('|'),
   $currEl = currSlot[0].length ? $('[data-atg-url=' + currSlot[0] + ']') : null,
   wcmLocation = currSlot[2] || null;

 if ($currEl !== null && wcmLocation !== null) {
  console.log($currEl);
  $.ajax({
   url: wcmLocation,
   success: buildSuccessHandler($currEl),
   error: updateSlots.checkDefault
  }); // $.ajax
 }
} // for : atgSlots

function buildSuccessHandler($thisEl) {
    return function(html) {
        console.log($thisEl);
        updateSlots.setContent($thisEl, html);
    };
}
```

(I'm assuming all of this code is contained inside a function somewhere.)

More about closures and this live reference thing in this blog post: [*"Closures are not complicated"*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

Comment: TJ: Thanks for the VERY thorough explanation. I guess I should have realized this do to the async nature of events. Thanks for the help!

Comment: and yes, this is all in a function

Answer (score 0):

The problem will probably be that when the AJAX callback is called $currEl will be set to a different value, or null, as it will take the value of $currEl when the callback is called, not when the AJAX function is declared.